# Does Tokyo based PASMO work in Kyoto?

Tags: public-transport, japan, tokyo, kyoto

I have a PASMO which I bought in Tokyo, but I would like to use it in Kyoto for a few days. Will it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, The PASMO website ([Japanese](https://www.pasmo.co.jp/about/sharing/) | [English](https://www.pasmo.co.jp/visitors/en/area/)) states one can use a PASMO card across Japan if the transport provider accepts an IC card for travel (indicated by [the IC mark on their card readers](https://www.pasmo.co.jp/visitors/en/area/)). This is enabled by the [National Transport IC Card Shared Use Service](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A4%E9%80%9A%E7%B3%BBIC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E7%9B%B8%E4%BA%92%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9) among card issuers.

In other words, if the transport operator takes ICOCA (the IC Card issued in Kyoto and co.), they will take a PASMO card.* The non-exhaustive list of operators includes:

- JR West - both train and buses ([Japanese](https://www.jr-odekake.net/icoca/area/) | [English](https://www.westjr.co.jp/global/en/ticket/icoca-haruka/pdf/icoca_area.pdf))
- [Kyoto Subway and City Buses](https://www2.city.kyoto.lg.jp/kotsu/webguide/en/ticket/ic_card.html)
- [Kintetsu Railway](https://www.kintetsu.co.jp/foreign/english/about/howto/before.html#cnt2)
- Hankyu Railway ([Japanese](https://www.hankyu.co.jp/ticket/stacia-pitapa/ic.html) | [English](https://www.hankyu.co.jp/global/en/traffic/faq/index.html))
- [Keihan Railway](https://www.keihan.co.jp/travel/en/trains/purchasing-tickets/)
- Keihan Buses (e.g. [the station loop](https://www.keihan.co.jp/travel/en/pdf/useful-files/keihanshuttlebus.pdf))

The only downside with using a PASMO card in Kyoto is that station staff won't be able to help you fix any problems related to the card itself, as they are not the card issuer.

---

Side note: The above applies to both regular PASMO and PASMO PASSPORT (the tourist version) cards, but the latter is [only valid for 28 days after issuance](https://www.pasmo.co.jp/visitors/en/attention/).

Comment: Can confirm. The PASMO is working.